# Help Finding an Example of Given Condition

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the problem: Give an example of the following if possible.

A sequence of nested unbounded closed intervals $L_1 \supseteq L_2 \supseteq L_3 \supseteq \ldots$ with ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^\infty$ $L_n$
= $\emptyset$. (An unbounded closed interval has the form $[a, \infty) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge a\}$.)

I am having trouble forming an example, if this is possible. If not, why is it impossible?

**Part 2** Give an example (if possible) of a sequence of closed (not necessarily nested) intervals $I_1, I_2, I_3,\dots$ with the property that ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^N \neq \emptyset$ for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$, but ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^\infty = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Consider the chain of intervals $L_n = [n, \infty)$. Suppose there exists $a \in \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty L_n$, then $a \geq n$ for all natural numbers $n$ which contradicts the axiom of archimedes.

Comment: I just gave you the sequence $L_n$. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: took me a while to understand, i added a part 2 which is somewhat similar that i am also having trouble with

Comment: @rover2 You've asked a question where the same answer given still applies...